# JPA : Re-use Id generated from a sequence for a new version of the same object having composite PK (ID + VERSION)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have entity **A** with **composite PK [ id(generated from sequence) + version ]**.

For a brand new record I want to pick the id from a sequence defined in the DB side.
Lets say its created like below

```
ID     VERSION
1      0
```

Next time, I want a new version of the same Id to be created like below

```
ID     VERSION
1      0
1      1
```

Note : in the second case I don't want it to be generated by the sequence generator, coz I want to manually provide it.

Is it possible in JPA/Hibernate ? If possible could someone please tell how to do it ?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate ORM [doesn't support the generation of id with composite keys](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-generated).

You can probably run a native SQL when you create a new object.
With PostgreSQL for  example:

```
Long id = (Long) em.createNativeQuery("SELECT nextval('mysequence')").getSingleResult();
Long version =  ...;

EmbeddedId id = new EmbeddedId(id, version);
```

Where EmebeddedId is the composite key of your entity:

```
@Entity
class Example {
   @Id
   EmbeddedId id;

   ...
}

@Embeddable
class EventId implements Serializable {
    Long id;
    Long version;

    ...
}
```

Where `mysequence` is the name of a sequence on the database.